# is javadoc a good way to support software quality in documentation of code?

Tags: quality, documentation

I have generated the javadoc for my app, but my question is if I want really support software quality in documentation of code, Its just ok with the javadoc, or  what else to do?

thanks

Comment: Hi @Bentham, welcome to Project Management SE, a place for project managers to ask questions about the field of project management. It appears your question has been asked and answered on our site for professional and enthusiast programmers and hence is off-topic on this site. Here is the link to [Programmers SE - More Resources on Javadocs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=javadoc) that I hope you find helpful.  Additionally, please see our [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) to get an idea of what kinds of questions are considered on-topic here.  Thanks for participating!

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/36134/javadoc-usage-on-real-projects.  Here is another example that may help provide you with the answers you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc is a good way to document the purpose and public interface of a class.  When refactoring a class I would expect the Javadoc to remain untouched.  Other than when making changes to the Interface that add or deprecate functionality it should be stable.  Clarifications of the Javadoc should be done if required.

Package documentation can provide additional documentation.  Many packages can be used quite well based solely on their Javadoc.  Good Javadoc should be complete enough that programmers can use the classes without the code.  That said, Javadoc is mainly useful to programmers rather than other users of the code.

Javadoc is not an appropriate tool for user documents, nor for design documentation.  The appropriate user documentation depends on the complexity of the application.

Additional code documentation you may want includes:

- Build and distribution packaging instructions.
- Instructions on setting up a development and testing environment.
- Documentation of the development process.
- A bug database.
- A list of dependencies (required libraries etc.).
- Documentation on design decisions.
- Suggested process improvements to any of the above for the next project. (Post development review documentation.)

If you build more applications, the first three items should be similar.  If you use a tool for the bug database, you may be able to use it more multiple applications.  The final three items should be generated for each application, although I would expect overlap on the development process and dependencies.

As you develop more applications, strive to improve your process and product.

Answer (score 1):

If Javadocs can be generated, then they cannot tell you any more about the code than is already in the code.

Self-commenting code will normally be easier to read than Javadocs. If you remove any Javadocs which add no new information, the code will be even easier to read still. Adding Javadocs manually to explain any oddities is better than generating reams of comments that nobody uses.

The best way to document the code and support the quality of that documentation is to provide examples of how to use the code together with a description of why that code is valuable. These are also called unit tests, and will not only improve the quality of your documentation, but the quality of the code itself.